# How to not let the text have a new line in case of overflow

Tags: css, width, font-size

I am making a list, which some items of the list are short and some or really ling. I dont want to make a new line if the text is long.  I am looking for a way to not let make a new line and just reduce the font size then it can sit in one single line. Something like line-width ?! or what if I want to not show the rest of the text when it goes to next line. So if the text is bigger that a line it just put ... and not show the rest in next line.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
  .Music li .songName{
    background:url(img/play-button.png) no-repeat left center;
    background-size:40px;
    padding-left:45px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:40px; 
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; 
    font-weight:300;
   }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Basically, you want a conditional, that says if the line is long, make the font size smaller?

Comment: @JoshC Yh, or what if I want to not show the rest of the text that goes to next line. So if the text is bigger that a line it just put ... and not show the rest of the line.

Answer (score 1):

In plain css i think its not possible, or it will be not cross-browser compatable(especially IE). so the solutions are with javascript/jQuery. i found this plugin http://fittextjs.com/ which may help you resize the text( havent tried it yet). 

Other solution i was thinking about is adding the text in div/span element and measuring the width of it and the parent div, and making the resize on page load(something like this descussion here: http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/is-it-possible-to-adapt-font-size-to-div-width/) i hope this helps you in your research and fixing your problem :) and here is example from the topic (http://jbdes.net/dev/js/fontsize.html). it must be modified a little

example: if ($("span").width > $("div").width) then do the resizing.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was thinking to not use JS just to keep it simple. event it would be good if it could only not let any new line if text is longer that widths and puts ... to show it continues. However I really appreciate for your help and this two plugins seem do the job.